# Python AttributeError: module 'websocket' has no attribute 'WebSocketApp' in Docker container

Tags: python, docker, websocket

I have no issues using WebSocketApp when running from the command line, but I can't figure out the issue when I try to run as a container. Most text points to websocket-client needing to be installed but I have done that. I've searched everything I can find. Here is the simplest code set I can replicate with (using https://websocket-client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html)

CODE (test.py):

```
import websocket

def on_message(wsapp, message):
    print(message)
wsapp = websocket.WebSocketApp("wss://testnet-explorer.binance.org/ws/block", on_message=on_message)
wsapp.run_forever()
```

requirements.txt:

```
gevent==23.9.1
greenlet==3.0.1
pytz==2023.3.post1
websocket==0.2.1
websocket-client==1.6.4
websockets==12.0
zope.event==5.0
zope.interface==6.1
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9-slim-buster

WORKDIR /python-docker
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
```

ENTRYPOINT ["python", "test.py"]

Result is always the error: AttributeError: module 'websocket' has no attribute 'WebSocketApp'

I've tried changing the base image to be the full python install (python:3.9) and I tried generating a requirements.txt from my command line environment where it works (has a bunch more libraries installed) and still doesn't work.

Comment: Do you have a file named `websocket.py` in your directory?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I suspect the issue with the inclusion of ```websocket=0.2.1```.

Comment: Hi - I have been a long time user of stackoverflow - its always helped me to resolve everything but I can't figure this one out. I don't have any files called websocket.py. I'm not sure I understand the inclusion of websocket=0.2.1? I did a pip install websocket as that is the key library I'm using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove websocket from requirements.txt and it works fine.

The [websocket 0.2.1 package](https://pypi.org/project/websocket/) seems to be some rogue package without a description, last released in 2010. Use websocket-client instead.